# inserting multidimensional array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

i want to insert data from multidimensional array into mysql but while looping it loop more than necessary. i mean i want it to enter 6 records but i got many records. i knew i have problem with my  mysql query location but have tried many techniques but all in void. this is my code 
please help me

```
<?php
$primary = array(
    "array 1"=> array("clas" => "val 1","pupil" => "val 2","subject" => "val 3"),
    "array 2 "=> array("clas" => "val 1","pupil" => "val 2","subject" => "val 3"),
    "array  3" =>  array("clas" => "val 1","pupil" => "val 2","subject" => "val 3"),
    "array  4" => array("clas" => "val 1","pupil" => "val 2","subject" => "val 3"),
    "array  5" =>  array("clas" => "val 1","pupil" => "val 2","subject" => "val 3"),
    "array  6" =>  array("clas" => "val 1","pupil" => "val 2","subject" => "val 3"),
);
foreach($primary as $t => $value){
    $class =$t;
    $clas = $primary[$t]["clas"];
    $pupil =  $primary[$t]["pupil"];
    $sub =$primary[$t]["subject"];
    mysql_query("insert into tablename( f1, f2, f3) values('$clas','$pupil','$sub')");
}
```

Comment: This would only ever insert 6 records... but unless you delete the inserts done by previous test runs of the script, you'll keep adding 6 records each time.

Comment: _"i want it to enter 6 records but i got many records"_ smells like you need to define some unique key for your data, or create a unique index over the whole...

Comment: thanks but i dont know how i will define the unique key because am new to php and programing.

Answer (score 2):

You might try serializing them and storing them as a blob.  Serializing would turn them into a giant array of bytes that you could retrieve and unserialize.

Comment: Unless you don't query for the data, ever, this is about the worst solution I could come up with. How many rows & fields will that table have? 1 & 1? What if I only want those records with a specific pupil value? I have to get them all out of the blob and than loop through all of them with script?

Comment: Oh it's awful I know.  I'm just saying it would be cool if it worked.  You should really have an identifier linking to a separate table for a variable sized array like this.  Even one table with a static amount of columns and just leave the ones you don't use empty would be better than what I suggested.  But he asked that question and I gave the simplest answer I could.

Comment: Please only give those kinds of advice after you've established with 100% certainty I never have to work with the people that take it, or ever have to see their code... It almost physically hurts...

Comment: thanks for the insight, i now get by defining a counter function,sub array and insert function.then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the array isn't actually the badest idea if you don't need to search for the data. Another option is to choose another data structure for the data for example a binary tree and an object. The object you can serialze and unserialize and because it's a binary tree you can search it very fast in memory. It's a thing I actually think of myself.

Comment: If you don't need to search them why use a database at all? Save the data into a file.

Comment: ypercube: Because I can and also I want to use a binary tree to store and search for the data. I've never used such a data structure before and if it's not hundreds of megabytes I can be very efficient, too.

Comment: I really don't understand your point. Do you want to search/query the data or not? Do you propose using the database for that or a custom made binary tree in memory?

Comment: I need to search the data but it's also many attributes so I think to use a binary tree and serialize it. I don't need the database, too, but it has some useful functions over a file.

Comment: So long as he's only storing strings, even serialized it should still be legible and even searchable by the LIKE operator I think.  Could be wrong on this, might depend on the encoding.

Comment: user: TYPO3 is using a lot of serialized array. IMO it should be avoided.